# Webpack serve does not include exports on var

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a project using webpack, I'm trying to use the [webpack-dev-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server) package to preview my changes. However when I start the server and load the page the object created by webpack does not have the functions on it `Uncaught TypeError: test.a is not a function`, when I console log the object webpack creates I can see its an empty object `Object {  }`. Using the exact same webpack config to build the package and including it on my page works fine.

Here is my webpack.config:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    target: "web",
    output: {
        filename: "test.js",
        library: {
            name: "test",
            type: "var"
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Development",
            template: "./src/index.html",
            scriptLoading: "blocking",
            inject: "head"
        })
    ]
};
```

My index.js is very simple:

```js
export function a(){
    console.log("A has been called");
}
```

My index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
           console.log(test);
           test.a();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix from the problem here:
[WebPack output.library.type var is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866453/webpack-output-library-type-var-is-undefined)

After adding `injectClient: false` to devServer, and removing `scriptloading` and `inject` from the HtmlWebpackPlugin config, webpack serve now works as expects.